# How to access data inside v-for and assign to autocomplete component?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, v-for

I am new to vue and I've been struggling over this for a while. I have an external json array of airline details which I have looped over to only display countries. I would like to assign the countries to an autocomplete search function.

The autocomplete component i am using is https://vuejsexamples.com/simple-yet-feature-rich-autocomplete-component-for-vue-js/ 
I have modified it slightly to try and access the data with no luck.

Attempted to use computed to access the data

```
<vue-suggest
    :list="simpleSuggestionList"
    :filter-by-query="true">
  </vue-suggest>

<div v-for="data in filteredMyJson" :key="data.id">
      <div> {{ data.country }} </div>
</div>

import json from '../data/airports.json'
export default {
   data: function () {
    return {
      myJson: json,
    }
 },
components: {
  VueSuggest
},
computed: {
  filteredMyJson: function () {
    var self = this
    return self.myJson 
  },
  suggestionList () {
    return this.data.country
  }
},
methods: {
  simpleSuggestionList () {
    return this.suggestionList
  }
 }
}
```

Expected to show countries when begin typing, but instead returns nothing.

Comment: Just looking over the code you posted; are you missing [a single root](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#A-Single-Root-Element) for the component? In other words, your suggest component and your list should be wrapped in a containing `div` or some other element.

Comment: You're right, thank you for pointing that out!